# angular-ui ng-grid How to make the aggregate row be an editable row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I think that what I'm trying to achieve is having a `tree-like` inside the `ng-grid`. I didn't found such an implementation but I'm wondering if I can use the grouping mechanism

[image: grid example]

I need to have the group header be editable in the same manner as the rows below it (see image above), with exactly the same editable cells, acting as a master row. When updating one cell from the header group should update all the cells beneath that group.

From ng-grid docs http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ :

default value for aggregateTemplate:

```
    <div ng-click="row.toggleExpand()" ng-style="{'left': row.offsetleft}" class="ngAggregate">
        <span class="ngAggregateText">{{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}} ({{row.totalChildren()}} {{AggItemsLabel}})</span>
        <div class="{{row.aggClass()}}"></div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to use this option in order to render the aggregate row as I described?

Answer (score 1):

The below answer/comment is related to tree like structure and not related to making aggregate row editable...

If you are looking for tree-like structure in ng-grid, then you could achieve that with the combination of `ng-if`, `ng-click` and API(s) that updates the `ng-grid data` option on click of a particular row. Here is a sample [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgfI1cinuHPOtpTbMT7u?p=preview).

On click of a parent row, a toggle function is called to add/remove child rows in to the `ng-grid` `data`. (Refer to my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgfI1cinuHPOtpTbMT7u?p=preview) code for complete details)

```
$scope.toggleDisplay = function(iType) {
  $scope.displayItemDetails[iType] = $scope.displayItemDetails[iType] ? 0 : 1;
  $scope.selItems = $scope.updateTable();
};


$scope.updateTable = function() {
  var selItems = [];
  for (var i in $scope.allItems) {
    var iType = $scope.allItems[i]["Type"];

    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.displayItemDetails[iType])) {
      $scope.displayItemDetails[iType] = 0;
    }

    if (1 == $scope.displayItemDetails[iType]) {
      $scope.allItems[i]["Summary"] = '-';
    } else {
      $scope.allItems[i]["Summary"] = '+';
    }
    selItems.push($scope.allItems[i]);

    if ($scope.displayItemDetails[iType]) {
      for (var j in $scope.allItems[i]["Details"]) {
        $scope.allItems[i]["Details"][j]["Summary"] = "";
        selItems.push($scope.allItems[i]["Details"][j]);
      }
    }

  }
  return selItems;
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'selItems',
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'Summary',
    displayName: '',
    cellTemplate: summaryCellTemplate,
    width: 30
  }, {
    field: 'Name',
    displayName: 'Name',
  }, {
    field: 'Type',
    displayName: 'Type',
  }, {
    field: 'Cost',
    displayName: 'Cost',
  }, {
    field: 'Quantity',
    displayName: 'Quantity',
  }],
  enableCellSelection: false,
  enableColumnResize: true
};
```